# Flutter (Dart) to Android - Pass Image

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/1/image.jpg');
```

I read the image in dart by the above code.
By Platform Channel, Java accepts only byte[]

So, I have to send the image as `Unit8Lists`

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/1/image.jpg');
bytes.buffer.asUint8List()
```

After receiving the `bytes` in android studio, how do I again convert it to Uri? So I can use the android intent's `EXTRA_STREAM` to share an image

```
try {
      await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod('passImage', {
        'image': bytes.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'type': 'image/jpeg',
        'name': 'image.jpg'
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
byte[] image = call.argument("image");
//How to convert this byte[] to Uri?
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contents of the array of bytes.

Let assume that your array of bytes are URI characters, you can use the following code:

```
byte [] image = <your byte array>;
String s = new String(image, "UTF-8");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
```